# Asp.net Chart control multiple series binding 3 Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, stacked-chart

Hi everyone hope you are ok i need help for creating asp.net control charts. I need to create two charts.

Chart 1 - Stacked column chart

I have 3 attributes status, date and saleAmount 
i need to create the chart to display the values like this x axis( months), y axis saleAmount and point to display the status and  count it.

```
    private void bind10()
{
            //Fetch the Statistical data from database.
            string query = "SELECT status, DATEPART(Month, Date) as [Year], COUNT(weightedValue) as [Total]";
query += " FROM SalesActivity INNER JOIN STATUS ON SalesActivity.Status_ID = STATUS.Status_ID  WHERE status IN ('Request for info', 'Quotation', 'Negotiating','Order Placed', 'Lost' )";
            query += " GROUP BY status, DATEPART(Month, Date)";
            DataTable dt = GetData(query);

//Get the DISTINCT Countries.
List<string> statuses = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          select p.Field<string>("status")).Distinct().ToList();

            //Loop through the Countries.
            foreach (string status in statuses)
            {

                //Get the Year for each Country.
                int[] x = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                           where p.Field<string>("status") == status
                           orderby p.Field<int>("Year") ascending
                           select p.Field<int>("Year")).ToArray();

//Get the Total of Orders for each Country.
int[] y = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
           where p.Field<string>("status") == status
           orderby p.Field<int>("Year") ascending
           select p.Field<int>("Total")).ToArray();

//Add Series to the Chart.
Chart10.Series.Add(new Series(status));
                Chart10.Series[status].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                Chart10.Series[status].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
                Chart10.Series[status].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);

                Chart10.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Chart 2  Stacked column chart

I have 2 attributes  date and saleAmount 
i need to create the chart to display the values like this x axis( months), y axis saleAmount and point to display the different years for each month.

I tried to look everywhere but didnt find nothing 
the code what i created now is not right
Please help

Comment: What is not right? Does it not compile, throw an exception or does it not show what you expected?